# MySql округление

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, помогите создать запрос. Округлить число в таблице, например 
1287->1290,  1423->1420, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией ROUND(), https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_round.asp

Comment: *Округлить число **в таблице*** Ни в коем случае. Исходные данные изменять не следует. Выполняйте необходимые операции в запросах, получающих и обрабатывающих данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round(1287,-1)` даст в результате 1290
подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

Comment: спасибо точно надо